# Запуск метода в скрипте от имени другого пользователя в linux используя python

Tags: python, linux

Запущен скрипт на .py c правами root. В этом скрипте есть две функции:

```
def func():
    ...

def func2():
    ...
```

В системе есть два пользователя: user и user2. Как запустить ***func*** от прав пользователя **user** и соответственно ***func2*** от пользователя **user2**. При том, что скрипт запущен под рутом?

Comment: Не понятна суть вопроса. Программа запускается от какого-то пользователя, и наследует его права. Часть программы не может выполняться от одного пользователя, а другая - от другого. Но в программе можно запустить дочерний процесс от другого пользователя через sudo. То что вы хотите - не понятно зачем, и как

Comment: Возможно вам нужно [это](https://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/158174-running-one-python-program-another-different-user) - суть та же, запуск экземпляра от другого пользователя.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Классическое *nix-решение для таких случаев это: `fork()` потомка ⇒ понижение привилегий ⇒ запуск функции.

На питоне всё это будет выглядеть как-то так:

```
import os, pwd, sys

def runAs(user,func):
  uid = pwd.getpwnam(user).pw_uid # получение uid'а по имени
  pid = os.fork()             # fork
  if pid == 0:                # потомок
    try:
      os.setuid(uid)          # смена пользователя
      func()                  # запуск функции
    except:                   # выход с ошибкой, если что-то пошло не так
      sys.exit(os.EX_SOFTWARE)
    else:                     # корректное завершение
      sys.exit(os.EX_OK)
    # noreturn
  else:                       # родитель
    return pid

pid1 = runAs('user1', func)

# ожидание окончания работы детей (по необходимости)
(pid,rc) = os.waitpid(pid1, 0)
if rc != os.EX_OK:
   print("Child exited with an error code")
```

Надо учитывать, что функция в таком случае будет работать в отдельном процессе со всеми плюсами и минусами.

Comment: Это слишком низкоуровнево для Питона. Там есть специальный модуль processing или как-то так, его нужно использовать.

Comment: @0andriy, и в нём даже есть понижение привилегий?